# Get element from set of tuples in F#

Tags: f#, set, tuples

I want to find tuple in a set by first two values and return third value of the tuple (or None if found nothing). I woluld like something like that:

```
type Point = (int * int * int)
type Path = Set<Point>

let f (x:int) (y:int) (p:Path) : int Option =
    if Set.exists ((=) (x, y, _z)) p
    then Some _z
    else None

let p:Path = Set.ofList [ (0, 1, 100); (1, 1, 500); (1, 2, 50); ]

f 1 2 p
```

But this not works because, apparently, pattern matching does not allowed in expressions. What is the right approach? Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with a two-step based approach?

Comment: @John Palmer What do you mean? First, find the tuple, and second, extract value from it?

Comment: @Feofilakt - exactly

Comment: @ildjarn _z is a varible pattern, but unfortunatly, it works only within "match" blocks

Comment: @John Palmer And how to find tuple? By loop?

Comment: well there are now 3 different ways that you could find the tuple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the set to list and use List.tryFind

```
let f (x:int) (y:int) (p:Path) : int Option =
    Set.toList p
    |> List.tryFind (fun (px, py, _) -> x = px && y = py)
    |> Option.map (fun (_, _, pz) -> pz)
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 5):

Iterating on hvester's answer:

```
let f (x:int) (y:int) (p:Path) : int Option =
    p |> Seq.tryPick (function
                      | x', y', z' when x = x' && y = y' -> Some z'
                      | _ -> None)
```

`tryPick` essentially does a find and map in one step.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty neat solution with `fold`

```
let f x y p = Set.fold (function |None -> (fun  (x_,y_,z) -> if x=x_ && y=y_ then Some z else None) |f ->fun _ -> f) None p
```

Comment: This does not work. It effectively check only the last element of the set.  f 0 1 p returns None

Comment: @hvester - woops pasted the old version by mistake

Comment: Could someone expand on this please, maybe @JohnPalmer. Thanks

Comment: @oxioxi - This was a while ago, but basically the fold iterates through the Set looking for something which matches and if it does puts it in the Some slot.  This probably isn't optimal since it doesn't bail early, but it is a functional solution. Something based on pick would probably perform better

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
let f (x:int) (y:int) (p:Path) : int Option =
    match p |> Set.filter (fun (x', y', _) -> x' = x && y' = y) |> Set.toList with
    | [(_, _, z)] -> Some z
    | [] -> None
    | _ -> failwith "More than one point was found!"
```

Example:

```
> let p:Path = Set.ofList [ (0, 1, 100); (1, 1, 500); (1, 2, 50); ];;

val p : Path = set [(0, 1, 100); (1, 1, 500); (1, 2, 50)]

> f 1 2 p;;
val it : Option<int> = Some 50
```

Comment: Sadly this is O(N) on an ordered collection; it could be O(logN) if `Set` had a `lowerBound` function...